# Serializing to/from Adobe AMF in C#/Mono?

Tags: c#, amf, zend-amf

Using Zend_Amf it's possible to serialize php objects to/from Adobe AMF format.
Is there an equivalent library for serializing/unserializing C# objects to/from AMF?

I'm working in Mono 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options.  Here's the best.

http://www.fluorinefx.com/

Fluorine provides a full client and server implementations of AMF over HTTP and at least server implementations of AMF over RTMP (I'm not sure about client for RTMP--we just haven't used it so I haven't looked into it).  It also includes classes that can be utilized directly for AMF serialization and deserialization.

We use it extensively in our application as an HTTP AMF server, for random AMF serialization/deserialization, RTMP server, and in the past we implemented a plain AMF over TCP socket server using Fluorine (which is no longer necessary, this was pre-RTMP support).

Comment: Thank you, Sam! Is it possible to use flourine in desktop applications as well as server apps?

Comment: @Cambiata, FluorineFx works as both a client and server for AMF data (server for RTMP+AMF, not sure about as an RTMP+AMF client).  If all you need is serialization you can extract those classes and use them directly (either by referencing all of fluorine or making a custom build that has just what you need).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently written a blog post regarding the Flash aspect of FluorineFx AMF data transfer. There's some open source code on github (linked to in the blog post) too.

Maybe it could come in useful : http://labs.specialmoves.com/code/flash-data-transfer-using-fluorinefx/